# What is the song that plays during the "Burn the drug fields" mission?

Tags: far-cry-3, game-music-identification

There's a song that plays on repeat during the "burn the five drug fields, destroy the boat" mission. I think it's kinda catchy.

**What's the actual name of the song and who performs it?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would be "[Make It Bun Dem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGpzGu9Yp6Y)" by Skrillex & Damian "Jr. Gong" Marley.

Comment: Fastest response I've ever gotten on a Stack Exchange site.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If I hadn't heard the song's name in a game website's game of the year discussion, I wouldn't have been as swift.