# What is the name of the song in the intro to Dexter's Industries?

Tags: hitman-absolution, game-music-identification

In the intro movie to Dexter's Factory you see a snake biting a dog and 47 is driving through the desert to the factory

> after abandoning/shooting Lenny in the Desert.

**What is the name and artist for this song?**

Comment: Downvoter(s): Any particular reason for the downvote? [Arqade has a lot of "what is the song" questions about games.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=song%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano%20) e.g. [This.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98661/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja Perhaps because it shows no research, as the tooltip suggests? The [Hitman Absolution article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman_Absolution#Soundtrack) notes that it is an original soundtrack and gives the names of the composers. The citation links to a game soundtrack site that indicates it's probably called "Dexter Industries - Infiltrate".

Comment: The Soundtrack part of Wikipedia is one sentence and only mentions a few names. I think my question is legit. And it is not "Infiltrate". That is just ambient music during the level.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Note that I said *shows*. If you knew that and had done that basic research, it's generally expected that it would be put in the question. Putting that in the question along with the statement that it's definitely not "Infiltrate" would make a good, well-researched question. (FYI, I didn't downvote. I'm just explaining why others might have.)

Comment: Close voter(s): How is this question off-topic? I understand the reason that SevenSidedDie suggested for the downvotes. I don't think that it also means that this question should be closed as off-topic. This is very much gaming-related, like the questions I previously mentioned.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't see your point. I could of course list half the soundtrack that is not this particular song, but what point would that have? If someone knows the song he does not need a list of songs that are not the one searched...  To the close voters: Please explain yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the song mentioned above is "Black Bandana" and the Artist is "Find Folting".